# I accidentally deleted the default postgres database

Tags: sql, postgresql

I accidentally deleted the default postgres database, and now I can not log into the psql command shell because it replies with the following error.

> "psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist"

Is there a way to restore the database? or just recreate it?

Comment: If it didn't contain any important data there is no need to restore it. You can connect to a different database: `psql -d some_other_db`. If it did contain important data, then just restore your backup (how depends on the way you took the backup). If you don't have a backup, it didn't contain important data.

Comment: thanks, how do you suggest I run the command "psql -d some_other_db" because the psql shell is not allowing me to log in to run any commands. it just returns the same error after i try to log in. btw I'm a noob to postgresql.

Comment: I have no idea what "psql shell" is supposed to be. But the `psql` command line client will most certainly allow you to specify a different database to connect to.

Comment: sorry I meant to say psql command and thanks for the help, I am now able to continue.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the default database again. That should work for most cases.

Just run:

```
createdb postgres
```

before, remember to become postgres with `sudo -i -u postgres`